# PHP merge Array_values to single

Tags: php, arrays

The array looks like

```
$arr = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [TEXT] => A
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [TEXT] => B
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [TEXT] => C
            )

    )
```

i am trying to array output like this

```
$arr = Array
(
    [TEXT] => ABC
)
```

i tried using array implode, but still no luck any ideas? thanks

Comment: `$arr = ['TEXT' => implode(array_column($arr, 'TEXT'))];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
    ['TEXT' => 'A'],
    ['TEXT' => 'B'],
    ['TEXT' => 'C'],
];

$new_arr = [];
$concat = '';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $concat .= $value['TEXT'];
}

$new_arr['TEXT'] = $concat;
var_dump($new_arr);
```